# yarn install failing import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3] invalid syntax

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-sass

When doing `yarn install` i get this error, but no issues one other projects, also used Brew to install node. Note sure what else should i try, any suggestions?

```
error */node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: */node_modules/node-sass
Output:
Building: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.1/bin/node */node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.1/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '*/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.18.1 | darwin | arm64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3 /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:686:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.1/bin/node" "*/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd */node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
```

- MacBook Pro M1 Max
- Node v16.13.0
- Npm 6.14.15

Comment: I have this problem after upgrading to an M2. did you finally come up with a solution?

Answer (score 18):

Fixed by upping the node-sass version to the correct version based on my Node installation as documented here: https://npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: to which version did you upgrade to?

Comment: Darn it i had more changes of the version so i don't remember but i think i've followed the versioning for NPM and what node-sass requires

Comment: this did not work for me :(

Comment: Here is a list which version of node-sass is compatible with which version of node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Answer (score 10):

The reason for the error is executing a Python2 program with Python3. The syntax of `print` is different between Python2 and Python3.

```py
print 'some text' # python 2.x
print('some text') # python 3
```

That is to say, the `node-gyp` package that `node-sass` depends on is still written in Python2.

The solution is simple:

1. Prioritize upgrading to Dart Sass (aka [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)) as Node Sass is deprecated.  [LibSass is Deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated)
2. Install Python2, add the path of Python2 to `.npmrc` or `.yarnrc`.

Regarding the second point, take macOS as an example:

```bash
$ which python
/Users/frankie/.pyenv/shims/python

$ npm config set python /Users/frankie/.pyenv/shims/python
```

Comment: how was this not the most voted? Thank you very much Frankie, I spent waay too much time on setting npm python, and yours just worked.

Answer (score 8):

After updating MacOS to Monterey, this problem appeared.
Simply reinstall and relink node version, and everything fixed.

Changed version to **node@14** and fixed it. What i've done:

```
brew install node@14
brew unlink node
brew link --overwrite node@14
```

Here is an article with commands I've used https://medium.com/@georgeenathomas/3-step-process-to-downgrade-node-version-using-homebrew-bc0b0a72ae27

Comment: on side note using Brew to install node i did notice that my node_sass is taking longer to process when doing yarn / npm install, this is on both my laptops running different macOS versions. Installing node normally resolves this issue

Answer (score 6):

I'm getting this error while building the Vue.js and adding the Buefy to it:

```
File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
```

It seems that in my case the problem was that the version of `node` was not compatible with the version of `node-sass` in the `package.json`.

So the solution is to find a `node-sass` version compatible with the version of node installed on your machine.

Since I'm working on a fresh project to fix I could simply update my `node` the the last version and then use the `node-sass` compatible with it. Check [this list](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) to find out what's compatible

In my case this I did the following

1 | I updated the NODE to the last version (v16 in my case)

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
n stable
```

2 | I changed my `node-sass` version to the one compatible with node v16 in the package.json which is `"node-sass": "~6.0",`

Now, if I run `yarn install` it works like a charm

Answer (score 4):

```
gyp ERR! stack   
import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
Invalid syntax
```

This error occur due to python3 is used for executing the python2-only command line. I have tried executing the command with python2 and it work fine.

So the solution is temporarily removing python3 and replace python3's path with python2's path in your windows Environment Variables. Then run the npm line again!

This work for me so I hope it help you guys too

Answer (score 3):

I removed my brew setup :

```
brew remove yarn
brew remove node
brew remove node@14
```

Then reinstalled everything without brew, this link helped me a lot : https://www.jurnalanas.com/node-js-mac-m1/

Finally reinstalled yarn :

```
rm -rf ~/.yarn
curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing this answer, the current version of Node was *18* and the recommended version was *16*. When trying to install a slightly older project, I was getting a request to install `node-gyp`. The specified error has appeared. I followed bdn's suggestion and installed *14*. Now, not only that it didn't require `node-gyp`, it also installed smoothly.

```bash
nvm install 14
nvm exec 14 npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed (mac os x catalina) by downgrading node@14.

Comment: That's not a fix.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was enough to remove `yarn.lock` and run `yarn install` again.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved similar issue by changing node-sass version in package.json to "node-sass": "4.14.1".

My "node --version" = "v14.18.0" and "npm --version" = "6.14.15"

Answer (score 1):

My `node-sass` version in `package.json` is 6.0.0 and my node version is 16.13.1. As the [node-sass documentations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), the `node-sass 6.0+` requires Node16 but I still get stuck with the same problem when using the command `npm install` or `yarn`

Then, I tried to downgrade to Node14, it worked correctly (??!!). I don't know why and can not find any solutions or explanations on google so far.

Comment: same issue happen to me also not sure is it related to python version

Comment: I tried to downgrade my python version from 3.8 to 3.6 or even switched to python 2, still not working

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem on the same hardware. Node 17 installed via brew. I checked https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass and it says node 17 required node-sass 7.0+. I set node-sass to ^7.0.0 in my package.json which solved the problem for me.

Comment: in my case changing node-sass to ^6.0.0 helped

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in
print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
parentheses missed, it should be
print("%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3]);

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30718261)

Comment: Although I agree that this answer is not very helpful, it does highlight the error that is causing the failure. It's because of the version of Python that's being invoked. That's why downgrading to Node14 works. There is an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70669213/gyp-err-stack-error-command-failed-python-c-import-sys-print-s-s-s-s

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to delete the file 'package-lock.json' and then run 'npm install'.

The answer "For me it was enough to remove yarn.lock and run yarn install again." from FedericoCapaldo pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just abandon `node-sass`, because it [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass). Instead I advise you to use `sass` npm package.

Answer (score 0):

In my mac, I had this problem and when I ran `python2` command, I had this:

```
> python2
pyenv: python2: command not found

The `python2' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.18

Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
      python2 and python3 to be found.
```

All I needed was `pyenv global 2.7.18` to add python2 to the global.