# gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3]

Tags: python, vue.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to npm install in a Vue project, and even if I just ran vue create (name)
it gives me this err:

```
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "c:\Python310\python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded c:\Python310\python.exe c:\Python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: c:\Python310\python.exe -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Upwork\\contact_book\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Upwork\contact_book\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

I tried it in another PC but it is working fine, I think it is because I need to install something (since the PC is new)

Comment: I'm assuming `gyp` is a Node package (I'm not a JS guy). At any rate, if it is, the maintainers need to update their install script. The `print "blah blah blah"` syntax is from Python 2, an old version that has been out of support for over 2 years and deprecated long before that. The correct Python 3 syntax would be `print("blah blah blah")` because [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function now.

Comment: I see `node-gyp` is now on version 8.4.1, while you seem to be using version 3.8.0, which was released in 2018. You definitely need to upgrade.

Comment: I tried `npm i -g node-gyp` but It still shows up the same error with the same `node-gyp -v v3.8.0`

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling `node-gyp`, then reinstall it? I use `npm` very little, so I don't know any tricks to get around it, other than trying to delete it manually.

Comment: Hey @MattDMo, I found out that Node 16 doesn't support it right now, so I downgraded Node.js to v14.18.0 and it worked, thanks a lot if you didn't tell me about the version I wasn't going to pay attention to it

Comment: @MehdiMamas downgrading Node to v14 indeed works, thanks!. You could answer your own  question and mark it as correct, so everyone who stumbled into this could see the solution

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @MehdiMamas pointed out in the comments, downgrading Node to v14 should solve the problem

```
nvm install 14
nvm use 14
```

Answer (score 5):

run: `npm install --ignore-scripts`

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, which worked for me (and in my opinion the better one), is to update the used packages inside the package.json.
I find the package/tool npm-check-updates pretty handy for that.

Comment: Sometimes you just want to use the old version, updating everything will cause a lot of errors (sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Volta, try use command `volta pin node@<node-version>` in repository dir. It helped me.