# How do I install node-sass on MacOSX M1?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I have an error with node-sass when trying to do a `yarn` on my M1 MacBook.

I have this error :

```
error /Users/antoinekurka/Documents/Freelance/Projets/NL/NextLevel/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/antoinekurka/Documents/Freelance/Projets/NL/NextLevel/node_modules/node-sass
Output:
Building: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/17.8.0/bin/node /Users/antoinekurka/Documents/Freelance/Projets/NL/NextLevel/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/17.8.0/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/antoinekurka/Documents/Freelance/Projets/NL/NextLevel/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@17.8.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/usr/bin/python3" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/17.8.0/bin/node" "/Users/antoinekurka/Documents/Freelance/Projets/NL/NextLevel/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/antoinekurka/Documents/Freelance/Projets/NL/NextLevel/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v17.8.0
```

I tried to do it with node 12 & 14 too.

and in the package.json I have this :

```
"node-sass": "^4.11.0",
"sass-loader": "^9.0.3",
```

I tried different versions of node-sass but nothings work.

Everytime I try, I delete the /node_modules, package-lock.json and the yarn.lock

Do someone have any idea on how to fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you found the solution ? I'm getting the same issues and the responses at the bottom didn't work

Comment: Have a look on this link I think this will solve the issue https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1149

Answer (score 6, accepted):

node-sass is deprecated and many people have had problems installing it with the ARM architecture. Check here for more details: https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated. If you can, use sass instead.
`yarn add -D sass`

Answer (score 5):

I had that fixed by using `python2.7`.
With [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), you can do:

```
pyenv install 2.7
pyenv local 2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Big G is right -- stop using `node-sass` if you can. If you can't for some reason, there is a long discussion on potential ways to solve related issues here: [yarn install failing import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3] invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69936116/yarn-install-failing-import-sys-print-s-s-s-sys-version-info3-invalid)

Comment: `node-sass` is still far more performant than `dart-sass` when big projects are concerned