# npm install failing due to Python executable - React Template

Tags: python, reactjs, environment-variables

Good day

I have purchased a React template that I am trying to get up and running locally. When I run an 'npm i' command, I get the following error message:

```
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python39\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Projects\\Mondo\\Molo Product Managment\\Code\\template\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\Mondo\Molo Product Managment\Code\template\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I have installed the latest version of Python from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/

And have updated my environment variables (both the 'User variables' as well as the 'System Variables") to include the path that it was installed to:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I would be extremely grateful if anyone might have some advice on why this is failing, and what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: It seems like the library executing `import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];` as external command. But the syntax looks like python 2 not 3.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM thank you kindly for your response. Do you think it would be worth it to try and install an older version of Python?

Comment: yes, temporary method could be downgrading the python to 2 and proceed installation, but I guess it is because the node-sass does not match with the version of the node, you could view it in here: https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy

Comment: @phunder See [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/v3.8.0/lib/configure.js#L451). *node-gyp -v v3.8.0* is oldest version of the package and it uses python 2 syntax

Comment: Isn't it the same issue resolved by upgrading node-sass?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69936116/yarn-install-failing-import-sys-print-s-s-s-sys-version-info3-invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's suggestions. I have been able to resolve my build failure through a combination form the advice gained from the links provided. Here follows the steps I implemented:

- I downgraded to Python 2.7
- I ensured that 'C:\Python27' was towards the top of my Windows Environment variables
- I installed Windows build tools with npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0
- I deleted my package-lock.json file and ran npm i once more

After these steps, my solution builds and runs.